# Remove Double quotes and HTTP and HTTPS from each line

Tags: sed

Ive got the following output from jq which I would like to following to happen:

- each URL should be on its own line
- remove the double quotes
- remove The http and https if they exist
- remove any :ports

**The output is assigned to a variable OUTPUT and contains the following:**

```
"test.test.io:1337" "https://www.test.io"
```

I tried the following

`echo $ENDPOINTS | tr " " "\n"  | sed 's/^http\(\|s\):\/\///g'`

**Which gives me:**

```
"test.test.io:1337" 
"https://www.test.io"
```

**Need to mention this is on OSX**

Comment: Try `sed -E 's,"|https?://,,g; s/ /\n/g' <<< "$ENDPOINTS"` with GNU `sed`, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/RlcGq5).

Comment: Please also post the output you want to have.

Comment: It;s probably the `echo $ENDPOINTS` that's putting all your URLS on 1 line and making things harder. Try `echo "$ENDPOINTS"` instead. Always quote your variables, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

Comment: ah yes good point thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
endpoints='"test.test.io:1337" "https://www.test.io"'
echo "$endpoints" | tr " " "\n"  | sed 's/^"//; s/"$//; s~^https\?://~~; s/:[0-9]\+$//'
```

- remove the double quotes

  - `s/^"//;` - remove `"` on beginning of the line
  - `s/"$//;` - remove `"` on ending of the line
- remove The http and https if they exist

  - `s~^https\?://~~` - remove `http` optionally `s` followed by `://` on begining of thelin
- remove any :ports

  - `s/:[0-9]\+$//` - remove `:` followed by at least one number on ending of theline

Note: upper case variables are by convention used for environment variable, like `PWD` `UID` `COLUMNS` `LINES` `SHELL` `LC_CTYPE` `USER` etc. Prefer lowercase variables in custom scripts.

Comment: The OPs command line starts with `echo $ENDPOINTS` - they probably don't REALLY have all their URLS on one line and don't need to covert blanks to newlines, it's probably just a quoting issue.